# x independent of y, y independent of z, then is x independent of z?

Tags: probability

using $\perp $ to indicate independence:

If $x \perp y$ and $y \perp z$ then is $x \perp z$?

I started with: $$p(x,z)=p(x,y,z)+p(x,\neg y,z)$$
$$=p(x)p(y|x)p(z|x,y)+p(x)p(\neg y|x)p(z|x,\neg y)$$
$$=p(x)p(y)\frac{p(x,z|y)}{p(x|y)}+p(x)p(\neg y)\frac{p(x,z|\neg y)}{p(x|\neg y)}$$ 
$$=p(x)p(y)\frac{p(x,z|y)}{p(x)}+p(x)p(\neg y)\frac{p(x,z|\neg y)}{p(x)}$$
$$=p(y)p(x,z|y)+p(\neg y)p(x,z|\neg y)$$
but now i am unsure of how to work with $p(x,z|y)$.. if $x\perp y$ & $y \perp z$ then can you say $p(x,z|y)=p(x|y)p(z|y)=p(x)p(z)$?

thank you

Answer (score 8):

Take $z=x$ to get a  counterexample. $x$ cannot be independent of itself unless it is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

It's helpful about the meaning of independence, not just the formula. Events $A$ and $B$ are independent if information about one of them does not affect the probability of the other.

The probability of rain here (in Boston) is pretty close to independent of the probability of rain in north London and the rain in south London. But those two events are surely correlated.

Put rain in Boston between rain in those two parts of London and you have a counterexample to transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the context of the problem, there’s nothing to say A and C can’t be the same thing, Then they’re completely dependent on one another, and if one is the independent of b then so is the other. So quite clearly, independence is not transitive